# Запуск одного скрипта node.js из другого

Tags: node.js

Всём привет!

Начал разбираться с Node.js и столкнулся на практике с проблемой, ответа на которую не смог найти (может криво гуглил, просьба не закидывать тапками, а направить чайника).
Есть фронт на Vue 3. На бэке Node и между ними поднят web socket (ws).
На стороне node для обеспечения работы ws запущен скрипт на сервере, который и обрабатывает все входящие сообщения.
Вроде бы все ок и когда я передаю сообщение, он его отрабатывает, но мне нужно будет делать огромное количество функций для записи разных данных в БД, для чтения из БД и прочее.

Я не хочу впихивать все это в один файл .js на бэке, это выглядит неудобно и неправильно.

Как мне, получив данные от фронта, запустить другой скрипт .js с передачей ему полученных с фронта данных, чтобы каждый тип запроса можно было вынести в отдельный файл?

Ну или в целом, может я не туда вообще смотрю и это реализуется иначе?

Comment: Зачем в один файл все пихать? Хоть 100500 файлов ) Посмотрите в сторону expressjs / fastify.. или микросервисы еще есть

Comment: Куда именно посмотреть, можете направить? Тема express обширна как сам js(

Comment: https://github.com/jstpd/auth вот пример сервера авторизации, для примера принципа риализации

Comment: спасибо, пойду разбираться

Comment: Пришло к вам сообщение on('message'), запускайте нужную функцию(она может быть импортирована откуда угодно) следующая функция так же может запустить еще одну или несколько. Пробрасываете все вызовы по цепочке, в обратную строну получаете ответ и отправляйте клиенту. Смотрите async/await и import/export. На самом деле, без кода, не очень понятно, что вы хотите реализовать и что у вас не получается или кажется, что не получается